# Can't uncheck "disable extensions" in Safari Develop menu

Tags: macos, safari, high-sierra, safari-extensions

After upgrading to macOS 10.13.4 my extensions in Safari were disabled. Safari Preferences Extensions tab says "Extensions can be enabled in the Develop Menu". However when I try to uncheck "disable extensions" in the Developer menu nothing happens and it stays checked.

Comment: Was your Mac on a network?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I "fixed" it by deleting the 'Safari Extensions List' Keychain item and then restarting. I believe this is related to some Keychain issues I've been having because the Reset Password screen appeared after I restarted (after 5 mins of a black screen). After I reset my password my Safari Extensions were back but my Keychain had been blown out.

Answer (score 25):

This worked for me on Safari 11--> bottom of developer menu there is "allow unsigned extensions" click that;  Now go back to the developer menu and click disable extensions...

Comment: thank you so much for this, this has been driving me crazy on my work machine

Comment: This worked for me, but reverted as soon as I quit and restarted Safari. As soon as Safari started backup up, the *Disable Extension* option was re-enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by editing the plist for Safari to reset a variable that indicated extension were disabled after a reboot. "ExtensionsEnabled" was already set to YES -- and now that I fixed it I cannot find the key that was reset. Take a look in the plist for Safari.

Comment: Do you know which .plist file it was in ?  in /Applications/Safari.app/Contents, I have fifty three files ending in .plist.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to trash all of my keychains, log out and then log in again.

Once the keychains were re-created, I could access my extensions in Safari.

I'd also note I was having difficulties logging into iCloud before trashing the keychains. This issue was also resolved at the same time. Anyone having both iCloud sign-in and Safari extensions issues both, definitely try trashing/moving your keychains.

Warning: if you're not using iCloud Keychains, you'll need some way to recover the contents of the keychains you've trashed/moved.